# Ubuntu Installation Error: [Installer automatically tends t restarts]

Tags: server, system-installation

I am trying to install an ubuntu server in my local system using VMware/Virtual Box (tried in both) but each time it reaches the step for system name and username details it throws an error.

I am using ubuntu server image downloaded to my system.

- Tried using static and Dynamic IP
- Tried restarting installer several times
- Tried downloading the iso file again
- Tried using 20.04 iso file
- I saw an option of upgrading installer as a first step but I skipped it, now it's not showing when I restart the installer
- Currently am using Virtual Box 7.0

Just to clarify again, the issue is happening just after I select the disk partition setting and the options for giving username and password appears, there it throws the error.

[image: screenshot of error]

[image]

Its looks like a network error, when i changed the Network adapter to NAT it is working also internet is available in system. Then i changed its network adapter to Bridged and tried each network type e.g., Intel PRO/1000 or PCnet-FAST III but same result.

When i set a static ip with DNS and gateway, its also accepted by the system and the firewall also showing the same ip leased out. But the internet is not connecting to the system. I am able to ping to other systems in the same network.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the *live* system & thus achieving the first installer startup & accepting the upgrade you mention it offered?  Otherwise have you tried opening up a terminal & commanding the upgrade of the installer *snap* ? (ie. `subiquity` but I'd likely try just upgrading all snaps)

Comment: when i tried network via NAT and skipped that installer upgrade it didn't show any issues, so that possibility we can rule out i think.